# Differential equation with two functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $f,g$ are positive functions over $\mathbb{R}\ $ such that:
$$af(x)g''(x)+(a-b)f'(x)g'(x)+b(a+b)f'(x)g(x)=bf''(x)g(x)+a(a+b)f(x)g'(x)$$
And satisfying the initial conditions of:
$$\begin{cases}
f(0)=g(0)=1\\
f'(0)=a>0\\
g'(0)=b>0
\end{cases}$$

I want to try and solve this equation.

I divided by $fg\ $ and could not use the logarithm because of $f''\over f$ and $g''\over g$.

If I let $w(x)=f(x)g(x)$ then the terms coincide with $w', w''$ but without the constants.

Is it possible to solve this equation?

Comment: In the same way that you need 2 equations to solve for 2 unknowns, I'm pretty sure you need 2 differential equations to solve for 2 functions

Comment: Probably you may choose any $g$ satisfying the given conditions to solve the resulting differential equation for $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
af(x)g^{\prime\prime}(x) + af^{\prime}(x)g^{\prime}(x) = a(f(x)g^{\prime}(x))^{\prime}
\end{align*}

Besides that, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
-bf^{\prime}(x)g^{\prime}(x) - bf^{\prime\prime}(x)g(x) = -b(f^{\prime}(x)g(x))^{\prime}
\end{align*}

Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
b(a+b)f^{\prime}(x)g(x) - a(a+b)f(x)g^{\prime}(x) = (a+b)(bf^{\prime}(x)g(x) - af(x)g^{\prime}(x))
\end{align*}

If we make the substitution $u = f(x)g^{\prime}(x)$ and $v = f^{\prime}(x)g(x)$, the given equation reduces to the following system
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
au^{\prime} - bv^{\prime} - (a+b)(au - bv) = 0\\\\
u + v = (f(x)g(x))^{\prime}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Thus, if we make the substitution $w = au - bv$ in the first equation, it results that
\begin{align*}
& w^{\prime} - (a+b)w = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (w\exp(-(a+b)x))^{\prime} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
& w\exp(-(a+b)x) = k \Longleftrightarrow w = k\exp((a+b)x)
\end{align*}

Since $w(0) = au(0) - bv(0) = af(0)g^{\prime}(0) - bf^{\prime}(0)g(0) = ab - ba = 0$, we conclude $au = bv$. If we plug in this answer on the second equation, it is obtained that
\begin{align*}
u + \frac{av}{b} = f(x)g^{\prime}(x) + \frac{a}{b}f^{\prime}(x)g(x) = f^{\prime}(x)g(x) + f(x)g^{\prime}(x) \Longleftrightarrow af^{\prime}(x)g(x) = bf(x)g^{\prime}(x)
\end{align*}

At last but not least, it can be described the relation between $f$ and $g$
\begin{align*}
& af^{\prime}(x)g(x) = bf(x)g^{\prime}(x) \Longleftrightarrow a\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)} = b\frac{g^{\prime}(x)}{g(x)} \Longleftrightarrow a\ln|f(x)| = b\ln|g(x)| + c
\end{align*}

Comment: You are right. So $k=0$ and $au=bv$ thus $g^a=f^b.$

Comment: If $au=bv \implies afg'=bf'g\implies a\ln g=b\ln f+c\ $ substituting at $x=0$ we get $c=0$ thus $g^a=f^b$.